# Can we use 'I think' after 'In my view'?

Tags: phrases, ielts

The following sentence is given in my book:

*In my view, I don't think this is a good idea*.

I know it very well that if phrase 'In my opinion' is used instead of 'In my view', then it won't be correct to use 'I think/I don't think' after the phrase. But I am not so sure about the above sentence. Can anyone tell me whether the given sentence is correct and if we can use both the expressions 'In my view' and 'I think' at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

"In my view" means "in my opinion", and thus, adding "I don't think" would be redundant, awkward and unnecessary. Either "In my view, this is not a good idea", or "I don't think this is a good idea".

> view noun (OPINION) ​ an opinion, belief, or idea, or a way of
>   thinking about something

[View (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/view)

Comment: I completely agree with you. Actually this sentence is an answer to a question as follows:(refer Q-2 3.2, pg 127, 'The official Cambridge guide to IELTS for Academic and General training', edition 2018)

Q- Rewrite the sentences using words in brackets

_Personally, I don't think this is a good idea (view)_.

I was quite surprised to see the answer, therefore I posted this question.